# why a fresh ESXI installation only uses half of my SSD storage?

Tags: vmware-esxi, ssd

I got a very weird problem when installing ESXi-7.0 U3:

My SSD size is 256GB (or 238GB actually, it doesn't matter)
But after installation, login to ESXI, it only shows capacity of 110GB!
So how comes half of the storage disappeared? so confusing!

Anyone got hints on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a new SSD and if not, have you deleted all partitions on the SSD before?
Is this a virtual machine or did you install it on hardware? If last, do your controller support the installation of ESXi? My first try would be to check the partitions with a ESXi live-USB. Otherwise I need more information to narrow down the possible problem.

Comment: Yes, brand new SSD, and all partitions are deleted. I installed ESXI on a computer(hardware).

Comment: Could you provide more information of your setup?

[VMware Compatibility Guide](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility) would be a starting point for hardware compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Tyr! I think 'batistuta09' has the answer for my question (see below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ESXi 7.0 installation may take up to ~138GB. Proof - https://williamlam.com/2020/05/changing-the-default-size-of-the-esx-osdata-volume-in-esxi-7-0.html

You see 110GB space available for VMs datastore. It is an expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks "batistu09": I think you have the right answer. Just cannot believe that is the answer! So confusing, but so simple.